# mac find -name *.png does not work

Tags: macos, terminal, find

I am trying to recursively search for a filename ending in .png
My find command works fine for *.js, but not for *.png.

```
~ >find dev -name *.png
~ >find dev -name bluerightarrow.png
dev/sandbox/ScheduleEditorTS/ScheduleEditorTS/img/bluerightarrow.png
~ >find dev -name *.js
dev/backup/ScheduleEditorTS/packages/jQuery.2.1.3/Content/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3-vsdoc.js
dev/backup/ScheduleEditorTS/packages/jQuery.2.1.3/Content/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js
... etc
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [“find” command gives different results based on quotation marks](http://superuser.com/q/181042/150988).

Comment: A coworker suggested I just use EasyFind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a `.png` file in your current directory and the `*` is expanded by your shell.

Here's a practical explanation. Create a directory called `test`, then another one called `sub` inside it and finally a file called `myfile.txt` in `sub`. Then `cd` into `test`. Here are commands to do that:

```
~ >mkdir -p test/sub
~ >touch test/sub/myfile.txt
~ >cd test
```

You can run `find` and you'll get expected results:

```
~/test >find sub -name *.txt
sub/myfile.txt
```

Now create a file called `cause.txt` in `test` and run `find` again:

```
~/test >touch cause.txt
~/test >find sub -name *.txt
```

This time nothing is found because shell expands the `*` and your `find` command becomes:

```
~/test >find sub -name cause.txt
```

There's no `cause.txt` file in `sub`, so there are no results.

To avoid this problem you have to escape the asterisk with a backslash:

```
~/test >find sub -name \*.txt
sub/myfile.txt
```

Comment: You can also wrap the pattern in quotes, which while more work in this one case, is usually easier I find. Especially once you need to search for patterns like '*blah*' or '*foo*bar*'.

Comment: In case the above comment looks inscrutable to you: I suspect that Camden Narzt typed `*blah*` and `*foo*bar*` without understanding Markdown.